# Is there any issues with my code since the slider is not working?

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, slider

I am creating a web page with a slider included, but the pictures are not changing. In addition, the last image is shown as the default one, which I think is the source of the problem, but I can't understand where the problem lays. The JavaScript code seems correct as there are no errors in console.

What is the problem here?

```js
const previous = document.getElementById('previous')
const next = document.getElementById('next')
const images = document.getElementsByClassName('images')
const pagination = document.querySelector('.pagination')

let imageNr = 0

Array.from(images).forEach(image => {
  image.style.display = 'none'
})

images[0].style.display = 'block'

previous.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log('click')
  if (imageNr <= 0) {
    console.log('min')
    imageNr = images.length - 1
    console.log('next')
  } else {
    imageNr -= 1
    console.log('previous')
  }
  Array.from(images).forEach(image => {
    image.style.display = 'none'
  })
  images[imageNr].style.display = 'block'
})

next.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('click')
  if (imageNr >= images.length - 1) {
    imageNr = 0
    console.log('last')
  } else {
    imageNr += 1
  }
  Array.from(images).forEach(image => {
    image.style.display = 'none'
  })
  images[imageNr].style.display = 'block'
})

Array.from(images).forEach(image => {
  pagination.innerHTML += `
    <div class='page'></div>
    `
})

const pages = document.getElementsByClassName('page')
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #6d6875;
}

#hero {
  width: 80%;
  height: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#hero-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 700px;
  width: 80%;
}

#slider {
  height: 600px;
  width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.images {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.images img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.controls {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#previous,
#next {
  font-size: 200%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pagination {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.page {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #b5838d;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Flowers</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body id="main" class="light-mode">
  <main>
    <section id="hero">
      <div id="hero-content">
        <h1>A bouquet for any occasion</h1>
        <div id="slider">
          <div class="controls">
            <a id="previous" href="#">❮</a>
            <a id="next" href="#">❯</a>
          </div>
          <div class="images">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587317997367-3d47566f9528?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80" alt="">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1458229865435-7cbe781270e4?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80" alt="">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1623406795110-99f1c4325084?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1548&q=80" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="pagination">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </main>
  <script src="js/app1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app3.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.4.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `const images = document.querySelectorAll('.images img')` you only have one images and that is the container. No need to do Array.from, just do images.forEach. Lastly you are 
Missing `</section>`

Answer (score 0):

You put the `class="images"` to the wrong html-element.

`const images = document.getElementsByClassName('images')`
Selects only the parent-html-element.
You have to put the attribute to each img-element

```js
const previous = document.getElementById('previous')
const next = document.getElementById('next')
const images = document.getElementsByClassName('images')
const pagination = document.querySelector('.pagination')

let imageNr = 0

Array.from(images).forEach(image => {
  image.style.display = 'none'
})

images[0].style.display = 'block'

previous.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log('click')
  if (imageNr <= 0) {
    console.log('min')
    imageNr = images.length - 1
    console.log('next')
  } else {
    imageNr -= 1
    console.log('previous')
  }
  Array.from(images).forEach(image => {
    image.style.display = 'none'
  })
  images[imageNr].style.display = 'block'
})

next.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('click')
  if (imageNr >= images.length - 1) {
    imageNr = 0
    console.log('last')
  } else {
    imageNr += 1
  }
  Array.from(images).forEach(image => {
    image.style.display = 'none'
  })
  images[imageNr].style.display = 'block'
})

Array.from(images).forEach(image => {
  pagination.innerHTML += `
    <div class='page'></div>
    `
})

const pages = document.getElementsByClassName('page')
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #6d6875;
}

#hero {
  width: 80%;
  height: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#hero-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 700px;
  width: 80%;
}

#slider {
  height: 600px;
  width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.images {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.images img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.controls {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#previous,
#next {
  font-size: 200%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pagination {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.page {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #b5838d;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Flowers</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body id="main" class="light-mode">
  <main>
    <section id="hero">
      <div id="hero-content">
        <h1>A bouquet for any occasion</h1>
        <div id="slider">
          <div class="controls">
            <a id="previous" href="#">❮</a>
            <a id="next" href="#">❯</a>
          </div>
          <div>
            <img class="images" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587317997367-3d47566f9528?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80" alt="">
            <img class="images" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1458229865435-7cbe781270e4?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80" alt="">
            <img class="images" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1623406795110-99f1c4325084?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1548&q=80" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="pagination">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </main>
  <script src="js/app1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app3.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.4.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```